# Excel and IE10 VBA Automation

Tags: html, vba, excel, internet-explorer

I have been playing with internet explorer Automation code. I have nicked some nice code that will log me in and search for what I need it too.

My next issue that i am struggling with is getting my code to Locate to a button within a table.

The table consists of several lines with different TAXI bookings for my company, I want my macro to click the amend Booking button in the specified Dates booking. I have been investigating the Source but it is different to the stuff i have been working with to log in.

I shall include my whole code and a sample of the source code for the booking.

```
Private Sub IE_Autiomation()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object
    Dim row As Long, col As Long
    Dim tbl As Object, obj_tbl As Object
    Dim Storage(100, 2) As String
    Dim QuestionList As IHTMLElement
    Dim Questions As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim Question As IHTMLElement
    Dim RowNumber As Long
    Dim QuestionId As String
    Dim QuestionFields As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim QuestionField As IHTMLElement
    Dim votes As String
    Dim views As String
    Dim QuestionFieldLinks As IHTMLElementCollection

    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ' You can uncoment Next line To see form results
    ie.Visible = False

    ' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
    ie.navigate "https://cabsi.cabfind.com/Account/LoginCabsi.aspx"

    ' Statusbar
    Application.StatusBar = "cabsi.Cabbfind.com is loading. Please wait..."

    ' Wait while IE loading...
    Do While ie.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    ' Find 2 input tags:
    '   1. Text field
    '   

    '
    '   2. Button
    '   

    Application.StatusBar = "Search form submission. Please wait..."

    Set objCollection = ie.document.getelementsbytagname("input")

    i = 0
    While i < objCollection.Length
        If objCollection(i).Name = "ClientName" Then

            ' Set text for search
            objCollection(i).Value = "REMOVED LOGIN INFO"

        Else
        If objCollection(i).Name = "UserName" Then

            ' Set text for search
            objCollection(i).Value = "REMOVED LOGIN INFO"

        Else
         If objCollection(i).Name = "Password" Then

            ' Set text for search
            objCollection(i).Value = "REMOVED LOGIN INFO"

        Else

        If objCollection(i).Type = "submit" And _
               objCollection(i).Name = "btnSubmit" Then

                ' "Search" button is found
                Set objElement = objCollection(i)
            End If
            End If
          End If
        End If



      i = i + 1

    Wend
    objElement.Click    ' click button to search

    ' Wait while IE re-loading...
    Do While ie.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    ' Show IE
    ie.Visible = True

        ' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
    ie.navigate "https://cabsi.cabfind.com/BookingQuery.aspx"

    ' Statusbar
    Application.StatusBar = "cabsi.Cabbfind.com is loading. Please wait..."

    ' Wait while IE loading...
    Do While ie.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Application.StatusBar = "Search form submission. Please wait..."

    Set objCollection = ie.document.getelementsbytagname("input")
    i = 0

    While i < objCollection.Length
        If objCollection(i).Name = "ctl00$MainContent$txtClientRef" Then

            ' Set text for search
            objCollection(i).Value = "970"

        Else
        If objCollection(i).Name = "ctl00$MainContent$txtSearchByDateStartDate" Then

            ' Set text for search
            objCollection(i).Value = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")
            Else
    If objCollection(i).Type = "submit" And _
               objCollection(i).Name = "ctl00$MainContent$Button1" Then

                ' "Search" button is found
                Set objElement = objCollection(i)
        End If
        End If
        End If
     i = i + 1
    Wend
    objElement.Click

    Do While ie.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop


    'Set obj_tbl = IE.document.getelementsbytagname("table")
    row = 1
    col = 1
    a = 0

    Set html = ie.document
    MsgBox html.DocumentElement.innerHTML


'----------------------FROM HERE I AM HAVING ISSUES!--------------------------------  




    Set QuestionList = html.getelementsbyID("tblResults")
    Set Questions = QuestionList.Children
    For Each Question In Questions
    'if this is the tag containing the question details, process it
        If Question.className = "bookingID" Then
        'first get and store the question id in first column
            QuestionId = Replace(Question.ID, "question-summary-", "")
            Tbooker.TextBox1.Text = CLng(QuestionId)
            Set QuestionFields = Question.all
            For Each QuestionField In QuestionFields
                If QuestionField.className = "bookingID" Then
                Storage(a, 0) = QuestionField.innerText
                a = a + 1
                End If
            Next QuestionField
        End If
        Next Question
            'For Each tbl In obj_tbl
        'If tbl.ID = "tblResults" Then
           'Set TR = tbl.getelementsbytagname("TR")
           'For Each obj_row In TR
                'For Each TD In obj_row.getelementsbytagname("TD")
                  '  Storage(a, 0) = TD.innerText
                   ' a = a + 1
                    'If TD.ID = "passengerName" Then


               ' Next

                'row = row + 1
                'Storage(a, 1) = TD.innerText
            'Next

    'Next
    Tbooker.TextBox1.Text = Storage(0, 1)
    Tbooker.TextBox2.Text = Storage(0, 0)
    Tbooker.TextBox3.Text = Storage(1, 0)
    Tbooker.TextBox4.Text = Storage(1, 1)
    Tbooker.TextBox5.Text = Storage(2, 0)
    Tbooker.TextBox6.Text = Storage(2, 1)
    Tbooker.TextBox7.Text = Storage(3, 0)
    Tbooker.TextBox8.Text = Storage(3, 1)
    Tbooker.TextBox9.Text = Storage(4, 0)
    Tbooker.TextBox10.Text = Storage(4, 1)
    Tbooker.TextBox11.Text = Storage(5, 0)
    Tbooker.TextBox12.Text = Storage(5, 1)




    'getData
    Tbooker.Show






    ' Clean up
    Set ie = Nothing
    Set objElement = Nothing
    Set objCollection = Nothing

    Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```

Source for the relevant page.

```
<div id="divResults" style="float: left">

<table id="tblResults" >


    <thead><tr><th></th><th>Booking Ref</th><th>Pickup Location</th><th>Passenger Name</th><th>Destination Location</th><th>Date Time</th><th>Status</th><th colspan="3">Options</th></tr></thead>

     <tr>
         <td rowspan="3">
             <button type="button" class="btn_view" onclick="ViewBookingDetails(4713706);">View</button>
         </td>
        <td rowspan="3"><div id="bookingID">4713706</div></td>            
        <td rowspan="3"><div id="pickupAddress"> ST LEONARDS WEST MARINA DEPOT, CLIFTONVILLE RD, HASTINGS, TN38 8AG</div></td>
        <td rowspan="3"><div id="passengerName"> LTP HH970</div></td>
        <td rowspan="3">HASTINGS STATION PICK UP BY COLLEGE ENTRANCE, STATION APPROACH, HASTINGS, TN34 1BA</td>
        <td rowspan="3">03/03/2017 20:04</td>            
        <td rowspan="3"><span class="statusConfirmed">Confirmed</span></td>    

        <td><a onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to Amend this booking?&#39;);" id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnAmendBooking_0" class="btn_amend" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl01$btnAmendBooking&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
         Amend</a></td>
     </tr>
        <tr><td><a id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnBookReturn_0" class="btn_return" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl01$btnBookReturn&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Return</a></td></tr>                              
        <tr><td><a onclick="return confirm(&#39;Are you sure you want to Cancel this booking?&#39;);" id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnCancelBooking_0" class="btn_cancel_ASI" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl01$btnCancelBooking&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">
            Cancel</a></td></tr>



     <tr>
         <td rowspan="3">
             <button type="button" class="btn_view" onclick="ViewBookingDetails(4713705);">View</button>
         </td>
        <td rowspan="3"><div id="bookingID">4713705</div></td>            
        <td rowspan="3"><div id="pickupAddress"> ST LEONARDS WEST MARINA DEPOT, CLIFTONVILLE RD, HASTINGS, TN38 8AG</div></td>
        <td rowspan="3"><div id="passengerName"> LTP HH970</div></td>
        <td rowspan="3">HASTINGS STATION PICK UP BY COLLEGE ENTRANCE, STATION APPROACH, HASTINGS, TN34 1BA</td>
        <td rowspan="3">02/03/2017 20:04</td>            
        <td rowspan="3"><span class="statusConfirmed">Confirmed</span></td>    

        <td></td>
     </tr>
        <tr><td><a id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnBookReturn_1" class="btn_return" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$rptBookings$ctl02$btnBookReturn&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Return</a></td></tr>                              
        <tr><td></td></tr>
```

I need to firstly get the Code to Locate to the Booking information Name, Pickup local + destination and print this to the user form Text boxes. and then locate that bookings ##class="btn_amend"## button and click it. From there i am back to the normal forms for the website we use here at work.

Basically I am getting a little confused at to getting through the tables AND I also get an issue with

```
Set QuestionList = html.getelementsbyID(".divResults")
```

ERROR:438 "Object doesn't support this property or method."

I have tried adding Microsoft HTML Object Library but still not getting it to work!

Thanks for looking at this, If you need any more information or source code let me know.

Comment: Please also excuse the messiness of my code, I am purely experimenting with different methods and as such have some redundant code ect.

Comment: It's `getElementById` (no "s") - the method should return a single element, not a collection as for (eg `getElmentsByTagName` or `getElmentsByClassName`)  Id values in a document are supposed to be unique.  And you seem to have a leading period on the Id which shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thanks Fixed this now. I am now messing around with the table which is fine. I have another question though Within the table contents "innerText" is how i have been readin everything. however now there is a Button OBJ that i would like to store for later however i can find the correct terminology for .InnerObject/Name to search for  `id="MainContent_rptBookings_btnBookReturn_1"/class="btn_return"`   either of these. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you talking about the `a` link elements - those aren't buttons but maybe they appear that way in the rendered page?  The HTML markup is bad since it has multiple instances of the same id on the page.  You can get any links from each table row using something like `obj_row.getElementsByTagName("a")`

Comment: @Tim Williams Thanks tim, If there any way to store the links i find? for clicking on lateR?

Comment: You can store them in a Collection (for example) but they'll only be useful as long as the page remains loaded: once you trigger some other navigation they'll be lost.